# Checking of errors in DTD

Tags: xml, dtd

I require to write an XML of something like

```
 <student Name = "aaa">

 <subject id="abc">
   <assignment id="1">
        <name>ddd</name>
        <Submission>12/2/1999</Submission>
   </assignment>
   <assignment id="2">
        <name>ddd</name>
        <Submission>12/2/1999</Submission>
   </assignment>    
 </subject>

<subject id="hjd">
   <assignment id="1">
        <name>ddd</name>
        <Submission>12/2/1999</Submission>
  </assignment>
  <assignment id="2">
        <name>ggg</name>
        <Submission>12/2/1999</Submission>
  </assignment>
</subject>
</student>
```

As for my DTD file (as I am required to write it as an external DTD)

I wrote it as

```
 <!ELEMENT student (subject*)>
 <!ELEMENT subject (assignment*)>
 <!ELEMENT assignment (name,submission)>
 <!ATTLIST student name PCDATA #REQUIRED>
 <!ATTLIST subject ID PCDATA #REQUIRED>
 <!ATTLIST assignment ID PCDATA #REQUIRED>
```

The submission has to be in date format and i do not know what is wrong with this. anyone can help?

Comment: What do you mean with "*i do not know what is wrong with this*"? Do you have an error?

Comment: I do not know what is the error, I can't seem to check if I am wrong or what. But I just by looking at the data I've created, is there a way to know if there are anything wrong?

Comment: You can parse and validate your input XML against the DTD to check if it is correct. BTW, we're not here to tell if what you're doing is right or wrong -- you'd rather know what you want to do and explain what are the issues you are stuck with.

Comment: Can you explain "_The submission has to be in date format_" a little more? What format? ISO 8601? (The date format can't be a DTD constraint, but we can help you with the format of the date in the XML itself.)

Answer (score 0):

Like potame said, you can validate your XML against the DTD to check if it's correct. However, I do see a few things that are for sure incorrect...

- In your ATTLIST declarations, you use `PCDATA` which is invalid. Use `CDATA` instead.
- For the `student` element, you declare the attribute `name`, but your XML uses the attribute `Name`. Case matters.
- Similar issue with the `ID` attribute of `subject` and `assignment`; the case should match.
- Your DTD specifies that the `assignment` element must contain one `name` element followed by one `submission` element, but you don't declare those elements. (Also, your XML uses `Submission`. Again, the case matters.)

Here is a corrected DTD and instance. I also changed the formatting and order of the DTD to make it a little easier to read, but that part doesn't matter.

**XML DTD**

```
<!ELEMENT student (subject*)>
<!ATTLIST student 
          name CDATA #REQUIRED>

<!ELEMENT subject (assignment*)>
<!ATTLIST subject 
          id CDATA #REQUIRED>

<!ELEMENT assignment (name,submission)>
<!ATTLIST assignment 
          id CDATA #REQUIRED>

<!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT submission (#PCDATA)>
```

**XML Instance**

```
<student name="aaa">
    <subject id="abc">
        <assignment id="1">
            <name>ddd</name>
            <submission>12/2/1999</submission>
        </assignment>
        <assignment id="2">
            <name>ddd</name>
            <submission>12/2/1999</submission>
        </assignment>
    </subject>
    <subject id="hjd">
        <assignment id="1">
            <name>ddd</name>
            <submission>12/2/1999</submission>
        </assignment>
        <assignment id="2">
            <name>ggg</name>
            <submission>12/2/1999</submission>
        </assignment>
    </subject>
</student>
```

You should also reference the DTD with a DOCTYPE declaration in the XML, but I don't know how or where you're submitting this data.

I also don't know what "*The submission has to be in date format*" means. What format? ISO 8601? If you give more detail, I should be able to answer any question about the date format.